# uiActivityindicatorView in splashscreen creates memory leakage problem?

Tags: iphone, splash-screen, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to display UIActivityIndicatorView over splash screen.
I'm just creating a splashView and activityindicator over splashview in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   

    //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.

    splashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    UIImage *splashImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splashimage.png"];
    splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    splashImageView.image = splashImage;
    [splashView addSubview:splashImageView];

    progressIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(145,440,30,30)];
    progressIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    [progressIndicator startAnimating];
    [splashView addSubview:progressIndicator];

    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getInitialData:) 
                         toTarget:self withObject:nil];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    return YES;
}

- (void)getInitialData:(id)obj {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0]; 
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

It is working fine except memory leakage.
I'm getting message in console that autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking.
What i m doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be releasing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to make as ivar/properties ?

```
UIActivityIndicatorView* progressIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(145,440,30,30)];
progressIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
[progressIndicator startAnimating];
[splashView addSubview:progressIndicator];
[progressIndicator release];              // release
[self.window addSubview:splashView];
[splashView release];      // release
```

The following line is not none of my business:

> **I do not know, but first time i am seeing that some one is adding the
>   activity indicator on splash image. and why do you need to have
>   splashImageView, you could have directly make an entry in your plist
>   file for LaunchImage key entry**

Comment: Because i m loading images from web in uitableview,  i want to display indicatorview on splash screen so it will clearify that something is loading.

Comment: ahhh, that is very nasty way, so if you are loading the image in your tableview then why you are showing the activity indicator on app start. User might get confused that app is not starting or something is wrong. you should show the activity indicator on tableview. you can use cache if the data is same.

Comment: Actually i m newbie in iPhone Development still not cleared about many things about iPhone programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread method getInitialData must create and drain an autorelease pool. This is done automatically for the main thread but not for any extra threads that you create. Just add this at the top of the method:

```
NSAutoreleasePool* localpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

and this at the bottom:

```
[localpool drain];
```

The reason that you are getting the error message is because viewController.view is returning an autoreleased object and you don't have an autorelease pool in place on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems here. You need to release anything you alloc. The variables `splashview`, `splashImageView`, and `progressIndicator` are allocated but not released, so those will leak.

The message you are getting about the NSAutoreleasePool is because you are doing `getInitialData:` on a separate thread. `NSAutoreleasePool`s are per-thread, so you you need to do this:

```
-(void)getInitialData:(id)obj {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0]; 
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [pool release];
}
```